# How to overlay imageview on gallery ?

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I want to overlay imageview and gallery like below image

[image: i want like this]

i tried like this..

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp" >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:src="@drawable/title_header" />

<Gallery 
        android:id="@+id/Gallery" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but its not overlay. pls help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp" >

<Gallery 
    android:id="@+id/Gallery" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Gallery>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:src="@drawable/title_header" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`android:layout_marginTop="10dip"` give value as needed.